# How to use string builder to make command for cmd to include value from variable?

Tags: c#, string-interpolation

I need to create a string command for cmd, it already uses ${serverip} so I cant use string interpolation. Any suggestions?

```
string command = "tftp ${serverip}:/nfs/{MY_VALUE}";
```

I cant use:

```
string command = $"...";
```

It will read `${serverip}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try to use double curly-brackets `{{` to escape from  [Interpolated Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated)

```
string command = $"tftp ${{serverip}}:/nfs/{MY_VALUE}";
```

[c# online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/gctuJT)